# Add tab to the tabpanel on mvc

Tags: ext.net

I have a menu and some menu items.when I clcik to menu item I create new panle codebehind and add it to main tabpanel.so far so good ,but it seems for every click on the menu,panel created from the begining,plus,change place of the  the tabs.how can I solve this.

here is the my Index.cshtml

```
 <body>
        @Html.X().ResourceManager()
          @(
     Html.X().Viewport()
                        .Layout(LayoutType.Border)
                        .Items(
                            Html.X().Panel()
                                .Region(Region.West)
                                .Title("main menu")
                                .Width(200)
                                .Collapsible(true)
                                .Split(true)
                                .MinWidth(175)
                                .MaxWidth(400)
                                .MarginSpec("5 0 5 5")
                                .Layout(LayoutType.Accordion)
                                .Items(


                                    Html.X().MenuPanel()
                                        .Collapsed(true)
                                        .Icon(Icon.Note)
                                        .AutoScroll(true)
                                        .Title("menu")
                                        .ID("PNL34")
                                        .BodyPadding(0)
                                        .Menu(menu => {

                                            menu.Items.Add(Html.X().MenuItem().ID("1a").Text("test1").Icon(Icon.Anchor)
   .DirectEvents(m => { m.Click.Url = "Desktop/AddTab";
 m.Click.ExtraParams.Add(new { conid = "TabPanel1" ,pnlid="tabpnl10",viewname="Urunler"});
                     }));


                                            menu.Items.Add(Html.X().MenuItem().ID("2a").Text("test2").Icon(Icon.Anchor)
             .DirectEvents(m =>
                                          {
                       m.Click.Url = "Desktop/AddTab";
                m.Click.ExtraParams.Add(new { conid = "TabPanel1", pnlid = "tabpnl11", viewname = "Siparisler" });
                                          }));


                                        })

            )
                                ,

                           Html.X().TabPanel()
                           .ID("TabPanel1")

                                .Region(Region.Center)
                                .Title("E-TICARET")
                                .MarginSpec("5 5 5 0")

                ))
```

and codebehind controller

```
   public ActionResult AddTab(string conid,string pnlid,string viewname)
    {
        var cmp = this.GetCmp<Panel>(pnlid);
        var cmp2 = this.GetCmp<TabPanel>(conid);

            if (cmp.ActiveIndex==-1)
            {


                var result = new Ext.Net.MVC.PartialViewResult
                {
                    ViewName = viewname,
                    ContainerId = conid,
                    RenderMode = RenderMode.AddTo,
                    WrapByScriptTag = false

                };


             cmp2.SetActiveTab(pnlid);
                return result;
            }

        else
        {

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not going to work.

```
if (cmp.ActiveIndex == -1)
```

In WebForms it is retrieved from the Post data. There is no a WebForms-like Post in MVC. You should send all the required information with a request.

Also if you don't need a tab to be rendered if it is already exists, just stop a request. You can determine on client if a tab is already there or not.